# Access Google Chrome profile email address

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to access the Google Chrome profile and email address of the user using your Chrome Extension at runtime?

Something like:

`window.chrome.runtime.getProfile()`

Comment: See [chrome.identity.getProfileInfo](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity#method-getProfileUserInfo). You need `identity.email` permission.

Comment: Cool thanks add an answer to receive full compensation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [chrome.identity.getProfileInfo](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity#method-getProfileUserInfo).

Take into account that it requires `identity.email` permission to obtain the e-mail address.